# maven dependency jar file displayed as folder icon

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm making a maven dependency project and after the jar file is created the test project that references the maven dependency jar displays a folder icon instead of a jar icon.  Why is that?  How do I get it to display the proper jar icon instead?  See icon labelled "jed:2.0".
[image]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.anypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jedtest</name>
    <description>An application context test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>       
        <!--  log4j2 -->        
        <!--  log4j2 -->
        <!-- commons-io -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>           
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>            
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tacticalenterprisesltd</groupId>
            <artifactId>jed</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.41</version>           
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you show the pom.xml file?

Comment: Sure.  See edit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't that a reference to a local project within the workspace? Do you have the "jed" project in your current workspace? (Same group/artifact/version)? If so, remove it and perform a maven update on your project.

Comment: It is a project in my current workspace.  I'm not going to remove it though.  I don't want to lose all that work.  If that's all that folder icon means, I'll just ignore it for now.

Comment: I believe you can just close it. -if my answer answered you question, please accept it.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting.  I closed the jed project and reopened the test project that references the jed and the icon did change to a jar icon, but it's different.  It doesn't have the little padlock within the icon.

Comment: Is this JAR in a maven repository, or only resides in your local workspace?

Comment: It resides in both.  When I do Maven-lnstall it creates two jar files.  One in the target folder of the project and another in the local central repository.

Comment: I'm not in a position to check (on my phone, hence the broken English :)), but I'd suspect that the others have a lock due to being a "managed" dependency, whereas yours is not.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  I'll have to look further into the difference between a managed and non-managed dependency and try to learn more about that.  Thanks for your help so far.